# Is the redirect problem a server aliasing problem or a .htaccess problem

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

This past weekend, I ran into a redirect problem I have never seen before.

BACKGROUND: the site is a static site that was created by the site owner in a small, remote town. She figured out HTML and CSS amazingly well, but the file structure and CSS are poorly organized. So, my main task in helping her is to reorganize both while improving SEO. As I create a directory structure and move pages into the directories, I am adding 301 redirects to the `.htaccess` file. Then I test that the redirect works before removing the original file from the server.

ACTION: The first file move was to create a folder for a series of information pages about different minerals and rocks. These pages are not mission critical and made a good test. The first step was to create a directory called `MineralFinder` with a file called `MineralFinderHome.html`. The original file was at the root level and called `minfind.htm`.

BEHAVIOR: The first redirect line worked just fine. The second - fourth lines were

```
Redirect 301 /aluminum http://example.com/MineralFinder/Aluminum
Redirect 301 /aluminum/aluminum.htm http://example.com/MineralFinder/Aluminum/Aluminum.html
Redirect 301 /aluminum/process.htm http://example.com/MineralFinder/Aluminum/HowAluminumIsProcessed.html
```

These caused a URL not found error:

[image: Not Found error]

as shown in the image. The weird thing is that it is referencing the old file name without the camel case, but keeping the new directory structure with the camel case.

TECH SUPPORT: Tech support basically said they don't know why it's a problem and to use CPanel redirects. I'm not satisfied with that answer and want to know the cause of the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /aluminum ....
> Redirect 301 /aluminum/aluminum.htm ....
> Redirect 301 /aluminum/process.htm ....
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is *prefix* matching, so the first directive here will catch both `/aluminum/aluminum.htm` and `/aluminum/process.htm`. AND everything after the match is appended onto the end of the target URL.

So, given a request for `/aluminum/aluminum.htm`. This matches the first directive, and `/aluminum.htm` (the URL-path after the match) is appended onto the target `http://example.com/MineralFinder/Aluminum` which results in the URL in your screenshot, ie. `http://example.com/MineralFinder/Aluminum/aluminum.htm`.

The solution is to reverse these directives so the more specific directives are first.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as the earlier 301 will be cached hard by the browser. (It is often safer to test with a temporary 302 redirect as this avoids the browser cache.)

---

Or, use `RedirectMatch` which matches against a regex and is not prefix matching. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/aluminum$ http://example.com/MineralFinder/Aluminum
```

With the start and end anchors (`^` and `$` respectively) this only matches a request for `/aluminum` and not `/aluminum/aluminum.htm`.

> Tech support basically said ... to use CPanel redirects.

If you are happy editing `.htaccess` files then I would avoid using "cPanel redirects". If you have other directives in `.htaccess` then I would advise against using "cPanel redirects". And if you need to do anything slightly more complex then... you can't use "cPanel redirects". (Btw, "cPanel" simply edits the `.htaccess` file when it implements a redirect, but it doesn't always get it right.)

Comment: That worked like a charm! I removed the tech support's entries in CPanel, rearranged the order of my redirects, and re-uploaded the .htaccess file. It would be more efficient to use rewrite rules, but I'm trying to find a system that my client can use on her own when the re-organization is finished. She's a smart lady, but I think that regular expressions would be over the top for her. 

I was wondering where CPanel was storing the redirects. I was hoping they weren't in a database.

Comment: "It would be more efficient to use rewrite rules" - Well, it's arguably "more efficient" to use `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) like you are doing. However, you would consider using a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (which is what I assume you are referring to) if you have existing mod_rewrite directives - this is simply to avoid conflicts. (Note that `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` both belong to mod_alias.)

Comment: This is a case were starting with the general and pushing the specifics down doesn't work.

Comment: _Aside:_ Since `/MineralFinder/Aluminum` would seem to be a physical directory, I would consider redirecting to `/MineralFinder/Aluminum/` ie. _with_ a trailing slash (although this depends on what the old links are like. ie. `/aluminum` or `/aluminum/`?) If you don't and you request `/aluminum` (no trailing slash) then mod_dir will issue a second redirect to "fix" the URL by appending a slash. Two redirects instead of one. A minor thing really, just something to consider.

Comment: I wondered about that and will do it!